# cpp error: missing file

Tags: compiler

I have tried to compile a simple hello-world program hello.cpp and got the following message:

> > cpp: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
> > seems like missing file

from where do I download this file and where to I put it ?

thank's

Comment: Tried to compile *how*, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

cc1plus is the actual c++ compiler. If it's missing, chances are you need to install the g++ package.

```
sudo apt install g++
```

alternatively, you may install a bunch of compilation tools with

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Also, to compile a file, run

```
g++ file.cc
```

**not**

```
cpp file.cc
```

`cpp` is the **C** **P**re**p**rocessor, not the c++ compiler frontend.